# Распределенная транзакция jta в spring boot

Tags: java, spring-data, transaction

Как нужно настроить менеджер транзакций JtaTransactionManager, чтобы делать распределенные транзакции в разные БД? 
Ниже привожу полоную конфигурацию, которая
а) из-за неработающего менеджера транзакций не сохраняет в БД запись
б) проверить работает ли rollback при неудачном insert в одну из баз я не могу, потому что не работает пункт а.

Exception не ловится, в catch код не попадает.

Подозреваю, что менеджеру транзакций надо как-то передать dataSource-ы, с которыми он будет работать.

Конфигурация:

```
package sp.config;

import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;
import com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class NewDbConfig {

    @Bean(name="dataSourceA")
    public AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSourceA() {
        AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        dataSource.setUniqueResourceName("DataSourceA");

        MysqlXADataSource mysqlXADataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
        mysqlXADataSource.setDatabaseName("atomikos_one");
        mysqlXADataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        mysqlXADataSource.setPort(3306);
        mysqlXADataSource.setUser("root");
        mysqlXADataSource.setPassword("mypass");
        mysqlXADataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_one");

        dataSource.setXaDataSource(mysqlXADataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="dataSourceB")
    public AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSourceB() {
        AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        dataSource.setUniqueResourceName("DataSourceB");

        MysqlXADataSource mysqlXADataSource = new MysqlXADataSource();
        mysqlXADataSource.setDatabaseName("atomikos_two");
        mysqlXADataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        mysqlXADataSource.setPort(3306);
        mysqlXADataSource.setUser("root");
        mysqlXADataSource.setPassword("mypass");
        mysqlXADataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_two");

        dataSource.setXaDataSource(mysqlXADataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryA")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryA(
            @Qualifier("dataSourceA") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("vendorAdapterA") JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
    ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("sp.model.atomikosA");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="vendorAdapterA")
    public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapterA() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryB")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryB(
            @Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("vendorAdapterB") JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
    ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("sp.model.atomikosB");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="vendorAdapterB")
    public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapterB() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name="atomikosTransactionManager")
    public UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {
        UserTransactionManager transactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name="atomikosUserTransaction")
    public UserTransactionImp atomikosUserTransaction() {
        UserTransactionImp j2eeUserTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();
        try {
            j2eeUserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(300);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return j2eeUserTransaction;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("atomikosTransactionManager") UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager,
            @Qualifier("atomikosUserTransaction") UserTransactionImp j2eeUserTransaction
    ) {
        JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(userTransactionManager);
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(j2eeUserTransaction);
        jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }

}
```

Dao 1:

```
package sp.dao.atomikosA;

import sp.model.atomikosA.Customer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Service
public class CustomerADaoImpl implements CustomerADao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="entityManagerFactoryA")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void persistItem(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
    }
}
```

Dao 2:

```
package sp.dao.atomikosB;

import sp.model.atomikosB.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Service
public class OrderBDaoImpl implements OrderBDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="entityManagerFactoryB")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void persistItem(Order order) {
        em.persist(order);
    }
}
```

Сервис:

```
package sp.services;

import sp.dao.atomikosA.CustomerADao;
import sp.dao.atomikosB.OrderBDao;
import sp.model.atomikosA.Customer;
import sp.model.atomikosB.Order;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerADao customerADao;

    @Autowired
    private OrderBDao orderBDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void persistEmployees(Customer employeeA, Order employeeB) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Persist A");
        customerADao.persistItem(employeeA);
        System.out.println("Persist A OK - persist B");
        orderBDao.persistItem(employeeB);
        System.out.println("Persist B okk");
    }

    @Transactional
    public void persistCustomer(Customer customer) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Persist A");
        customerADao.persistItem(customer);
    }

}
```

И сам вызов сервиса из контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {

        sp.model.atomikosA.Customer customer = new sp.model.atomikosA.Customer();
        customer.setName("Maksat");
        customer.setAge(27);
        customer.setCustId(3L);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setCustId(3L);
        order.setCode(1);
        order.setQuantity(1);

        try {
            employeeService.persistEmployees(customer, order);
            employeeService.persistCustomer(customer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int del = 2;
        }

        return "success";
    }
```

UPD:

Когда я создавал простой JpaTransactionManager:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}
```

То в аргумент-бин emf я предварительно сетил dataSource:

```
em.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Таким образом мой PlatformTransactionManager знал dataSource, которым он управляет.

А при создании BitronixConfig мы не даем менеджеру транзакций никакой информации о dataSource-ах, которыми он будет управлять. Каким образом он тогда поймет какие базы у него в управлении?

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager bitronixTransactionManager() {

        JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        jtaTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        jtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }
```

UPD 2:

Сделал по аналогии с https://github.com/Cepr0/dual-db-demo . Запустил транзакцию в рамках одной таблицы, первое значение валидное, второе не валидное. С транзакцией не должно записаться ничего. Но первая запись все-же добавилась, а вторая нет, т.е. транзакция не сработала в рамках одной БД.
В рамках двух БД - распределенная транзакция - тоже не работает.
Что я сделал в конфиге не так?

```
@Configuration
public class BitronixConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager bitronixTransactionManager() {

        JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        jtaTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        jtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "sp.first.repo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "bitronixTransactionManager")
public class FirstDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        PoolingDataSource pds = new PoolingDataSource();
        pds.setUniqueName("first");
        pds.setClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource");
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(16);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        pds.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);
        pds.setIsolationLevel("READ_COMMITTED");
        pds.setShareTransactionConnections(true);
        pds.setEnableJdbc4ConnectionTest(true);

        Properties driverProperties = pds.getDriverProperties();
        driverProperties.put("user", "root");
        driverProperties.put("password", "mypass");
        driverProperties.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_one");

        pds.init();

        return pds;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("vendorAdapter") JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
    ) {



        Map<String, String> propertiesNew = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesNew.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJtaDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("sp.first.model");
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("first");
        bean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesNew);
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name="vendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name="properties")
    public Map<String, String> properties() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform");
        properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.enable", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "after_statement");
        return properties;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "sp.second.repo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "bitronixTransactionManager")
public class SecondDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        PoolingDataSource pds = new PoolingDataSource();
        pds.setUniqueName("second");
        pds.setClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource");
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(16);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        pds.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);
        pds.setIsolationLevel("READ_UNCOMMITTED");
        pds.setShareTransactionConnections(true);
        pds.setEnableJdbc4ConnectionTest(true);

        Properties driverProperties = pds.getDriverProperties();
        driverProperties.put("user", "root");
        driverProperties.put("password", "mypass");
        driverProperties.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atomikos_two");

        pds.init();

        return pds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("vendorAdapter") JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
    ) {

        Map<String, String> propertiesNew = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesNew.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJtaDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("sp.second.model");
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("second");
        bean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesNew);
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему менеджер транзакций не работает? Привдедите пример в этом случае.

Comment: 1) у вас SPring boot - а это значит что конфигурирование datasource нужно вынести в *.properties файл ресурсов 2) Работу с EntityManager оставьте для реализаций Repository (Jpa/Crud/etc) т.е. выкиньте ее полностью - кода меньше и удобней, но по производительности проигрывает стандартным Query JDBC 3) Если выводите данные во view слой переопределяйте реализацию как бин OpenInViewEntityManager и в 99% случаев о аннотации Transactional можно забыть

Comment: EmployeeServiceImpl:persistEmployees() и EmployeeServiceImpl:persistCustomer() - работают, но фактически в БД insert не происходит

Comment: Посмотри мое репо https://github.com/Cepr0/dual-db-demo, вдруг поможет. Там, правда Битроникс, а не Атомикос, но тем не менее... (обрати внимание - в главном pom.xml два профиля - для постгреса и мускуля)

Comment: @Cepr0 обновил информацию в вопросе UPD

Comment: > Каким образом он тогда поймет какие базы у него в управлении? - Посмотри файлы хххDataSourceConfig - в аннотации `@EnableJpaRepositories` указано какой менеджер транзакций использовать. Я там в репо нахомутал по видимому - хотел, как всегда, сделать лучше )) В результате у меня финальный вариант сейчас не заработал. Так ты откатись на два комита назад (на комит 'added readme') - все должно заработать (по крайней мере у меня сейчас работает), правда на постгресе. Запускай 'dual-db-writer' и смотри класс `WriteDataService` - там реализована транз-ая запись в две базы и случ-я ошибка с откатом.

Comment: Отрефакторил проект - теперь все работает как надо, и на постгресе, и на мускуле. Можете обновится. Сначала запускаете writer - он создаст структуру таблицы (ddl-auto: create-drop), а потом, если хотите можете запускать reader (у него ddl-auto: validate).

Comment: @Cepr0 А можете дать дамп БД?

Comment: Т.е. "дамп"? В этом же нет смысла - там данные типа "user1" - "user2". Структура таблиц соответствует сущностям - для user'а: id и name, для order'а - id и number. Или что-то иное имеется в виду?

Comment: Меня интересуют типы полей. uuid тип в mysql не поддерживается, версия Ver 8.0.11 for Linux on x86_64

Comment: Hibernate автоматом назначил binary(255): `create table users (id binary(255) not null primary key, name varchar(255) null);`. Да это и не принципиально - замените `id` на другой тип...

Comment: @Cepr0 сделал по аналогии с Вашим примером, но не взлетело. Можете в upd 2 посмотреть обновленный код?